# How to make the extra keys on my Sun Type 7 keyboard work in kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys

I am asking and answering my own question here in case it is useful to someone else, as it has taken me a long time to come up with a solution!

I have a Sun Microsystems Type 7 keyboard that has a set of 11 extra keys on the right hand side, and I would like to be able to program them to do something useful in kubuntu. But when System Settings is waiting for a keypress of the key to program, nothing happens for most of the keys when I press them. The exception is Cut, Copy and Paste: these three I can assign Ctrl+X, Ctrl+C and Ctrl+C to, and they work generally in applications (and, when I press them in System Settings, the correct key name is even displayed).

So how to get the other special keys to be recognised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I noticed that various Sun keyboards are listed in System Settings/Input Devices/Keyboard/keyboard model. So I chose mine, Type 7, with a UK layout.
Then I used `xev` and noticed that when I press any of the special keys, they are recognised and a keycode, the correct name and a keysym are displayed.
Also poking around the various X11 keyboard files it is clear that Sun keyboard support is definitely supposed to be there, at least in X.

After a lot of faffing around, in the end I used `xmodmap` to assign high-numbered function key values to the special keys. I put the commands in a script file I call `sunkeys`, which contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Assign F13 to F23 to the special extra Sun keyboard keys so that an action
# can be assigned to them. But Cut, Copy and Paste seem to work anyway.

if [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
  sleep "$1"
fi

setxkbmap -option ctrl:ralt_rctrl # Right Alt === Right Ctrl

xmodmap -e "keycode 146 = F13" # Help
xmodmap -e "keycode 136 = F14" # Stop
xmodmap -e "keycode 137 = F15" # Again
xmodmap -e "keycode 138 = F16" # Props
xmodmap -e "keycode 139 = F17" # Undo
xmodmap -e "keycode 140 = F18" # Front
#xmodmap -e "keycode 141 = F19" # Copy
xmodmap -e "keycode 142 = F20" # Open
#xmodmap -e "keycode 143 = F21" # Paste
xmodmap -e "keycode 144 = F22" # Find
#xmodmap -e "keycode 145 = F23" # Cut
```

(I'll come to the sleep bit in a moment.)

The function keys F13 to F23 are not on the keyboard but are in the X system and kubuntu System Settings knows about them, and when they are pressed it allows things to be assigned to them.
The `setxkbmap` line reprograms the right AltGraph key to be a right control key.

But although running `sunkeys` from the command line programs the keys ok, when I put `sunkeys` at the end of my `~/.profile` file, the keys did not get programmed when I rebooted. It turns out for some reason there needs to be a delay before you run `xmodmap`, hence the `sleep` business in the script above. So at the end of my ~/.profile file I now have the line

```
~/bin/sunkeys 15 &
```

This makes the sunkeys script sleep for 15 seconds before it does the `xmodmap` commands. The `&` at the end of the `sunkeys` line tells the shell to continue booting while `sunkeys` sleeps. Without the `&`, you type your password when logging in and then the system then appears to hang for 15 seconds.

I now have all the extra keys doing the obvious useful functions. I assign Ctrl+S (= save in most applications) to the big Help key. And Ctrl++ and Ctrl+- for soom in and out to the unobvious Front and Props keys as they are next to each other.

As a bonus the Compose key actually does what it is supposed to with no further changes: to enter `café` I type `c` `a` `f` `Compose` `e` `'`.

Update: I did a quick test booting from a kubuntu 20.04 USB stick and it appears that System Settings sees most of the special keys, and displays their names correctly, with the exception of Front and Props. So when I eventually upgrade I will still use this technique.

Comment: For anyone intending to get one of these keyboards for the extra keys: note that the older ones have an odd layout compared to modern PC keyboards (single-height return ley, backspace in a slightly different place, swapped Caps Lock and Control keys). You probably want to make sure you get the 'PC style' (and a USB version).